# I am having some problems changing the Content-Type in Kohana 3 to XML

Tags: kohana, content-type, kohana-3

Here is my code:

```php
class Controller_Call extends Controller {

    public $template = 'tpl/default';

    public function before() {

            parent::before();

            $this->request->headers('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

            $this->template = View::factory($this->template);

    }

    public function action_index() {

            $this->template->response = '<say>Hey! How are you budy!</say>';

    }

    public function after() {

            $this->request->headers('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

            $this->response->body( $this->template );

            parent::after();

            $this->request->headers('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

    }

}
```

When I load the page in firefox and I look at the Content-Type, I get text/html.

Why is that?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the headers on the response:

```php
$this->response->headers('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```